# Spring boot by default HTTPS but test profile with HTTP

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, integration-testing

Is it possible to define default `properties` file to enable `https` for example:

```
server.port: 8443

# SSL Configuration
server.ssl.key-store:/etc/pki/certificate.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: ${P12PASS}
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: ${KEYALIAS}
server.ssl.trust-store=/etc/pki/trust.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=${TRUSTPASS}
```

but perform somehow `@Configuration` with `@Bean` definition for `http` on `8080` port without any keystore information?

I would like to prepare some integration tests using `rest-assured` library, but when test is loading my default application context I get error related with not set variables like `P12PASS` or `TRUSTPASS`. I would like integration test to run application context without https configuration.

any tips?

Comment: You can use Spring Profile + Maven Profile to achieve this. Google how to handle those. You can take https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-blog-app/tree/master/src/main/resources as example. Note the application-tls.yml and the tls profile on maven

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to make dual port for your app. One is for Http. The other is for https. So it will not affect your test.

application.yml

```yaml
server:
  port: 8080

https:
  port: 8443
  key-store: /etc/pki/certificate.p12
  key-store-password: ${P12PASS}
```

Application

```java
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.Banner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class) ; 

    @Value("${https.port}")
    int port;
    
    @Value("${https.key-store}")
    String storeFile;
    
    @Value("${https.key-store-password}")
    String password;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        app.run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory  servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory ();
        tomcat.setUriEncoding(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createSslConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    public Connector createSslConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();

        connector.setPort(port);
        connector.setScheme("https");
        connector.setSecure(true);
        protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
        protocol.setClientAuth("false");
        protocol.setSSLProtocol("TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2");
        protocol.setCiphers("TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA");
        protocol.setKeystoreFile(storeFile);
        protocol.setKeystorePass(password);


        return connector;
    }
    
}
```